# How do I use Devart's dotConnect for Postgres with Entity Framework 5?

Tags: entity-framework, postgresql, dotconnect

I'm writing an application, following the repository pattern, that uses Entity Framework 5. So, I have my own DbContext class already, but it currently just uses the default Sqlite local database. I'm now trying to figure out how to introduce Devart's dotConnect for Postgres into this and make my DbContext connect to and use postgres. It looks like dotConnect provides support for this, but I can't make sense of their examples.

Are there any basic, working examples of this anywhere? I've seen a few but they're all pretty complicated looking and the code is too messy for me to comprehend just the basics. Is there maybe a good explanation of what to do at the most simple level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have answered you at the Devart forum: http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=28113.